# How to create javascript file using mongo shell

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mongodb, bson

A beginner to mongoDB. went through this website to know how to create a javascript file . 
[.mongorc.js](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongo/#mongo-mongorc-file) and

```
<code>
function insertData(dbName, colName, num)
{
var col = db.getSiblingDB(dbName).getCollection(colName);
for (i = 0; i < num; i++) 
{
col.insert({x:i});
}
print(col.count());
}
<code>
```

and the link is here [function insertData](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/generate-test-data/) ... the tutorial adviced to store the function in a javascript file called .mongorc.js . I dont know how to create it and use it and where to store it . need help .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### .mongorc.js

The [`.mongorc.js` file](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/security-interface/#mongorc-js-file) is used if you want to have some JavaScript loaded every time you start the `mongo` shell:

- On Linux, Unix, and OS X `mongo` looks for this file in `$HOME/.mongorc.js`.
- On Windows, `mongo.exe` looks for this file in `%HOME%.mongorc.js` or `%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%.mongorc.js`.

Typically you only want to store re-usable functions in your `.mongorc.js`.

#### Other ways to load JavaScript into a `mongo` shell session include:

- using the [`load()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/load/) command in a `mongo` shell: `load("/path/to/something.js")`.
- passing a JavaScript filename as a [command line parameter](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongo/#mongo-shell-file) when starting the `mongo` shell: `mongo /path/to/something.js`
- pasting JavaScript directly into the `mongo` shell (e.g. copy & paste from a tutorial)